# open a .jpg image in python using matplotlib.image in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open a JPG image using matplotlib in Python. Editor 'Spyder', Python3.6, WIndows 7

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

# Read in the image and print some stats
image = mpimg.imread(r'C:\Users\xxx\Python Code\mountain.jpg')
print('This image is: ',type(image), 
     'with dimensions:', image.shape)
```

But I am getting the following error... It says that except '.png' no other image format is supported.

Error :--
     image = mpimg.imread(r'C:\Users\xxx\Python Code\mountain.jpg')

```
  File "C:\temp\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", 
line 1284, in imread
    'more images' % list(handlers))

ValueError: Only know how to handle extensions: ['png']; with Pillow 
installed matplotlib can handle more images.
```

I went through various documentations. Which says that, in order to open a '.jpg' image, 'Pillow' must be installed. 
If native matplotlib call fails to open a image then it automatically falls back on 'pillow'. (correct me if I am wrong)

So I installed 'Pillow'. But I am still getting the error.

**Can you tell me what am I Missing ? (Strange thing is this same code is running in another computer. I have no way to verify what library is installed in that machine)**

Comment: You will get this error, if PIL or pillow is not installed or not found. You may test this by importing it yourself, `import PIL`.

Comment: I have added 'import PIL' statement to the code. But still getting the same error.
'Import PIL' executed without any error.

Comment: Does `from PIL import Image` work? (Note that this will not get rid of the error, but it is to find out at which point the use of pillow fails)

Comment: When I add the code `from PIL import Image` , I get a error message 
``Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-0f6709e38f49>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image

  File "C:\temp\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.``

Comment: ...meaning that the install of pillow went wrong at some point. Try uninstalling and reinstall.

Comment: I re-installed Pillow(5.0.0) in two computers. Both Win 7 (64 bit), Using Spyder 3.2.4, Python 3.6.3.

But still facing the same error.

Comment: I also saw the github post (link below), which is very similar to the issue I am facing. But still I don't know how to resolve it.

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2945

Comment: The issue you link to gives some solutions, especially `conda uninstall pillow` and then `pip install pillow`. In how far are they not working?

Comment: Thanks. I will uninstall Anaconda today , and then re-install Python from Python.org. And then I will install Pillow using `PIP install pillow` (no anaconda this time)

Comment: I uninstalled Anaconda.
    Uninstalled Python. (Cleaned everything)
    Installed Python 3.6.0
    Installed Spyder (using: pip install spyder)
    Installed numpy, pillow etc (using: pip install pillow--log log.txt)
    This successfully installed pillow-5.0.0
    Cleaning up...(last line of log)
    When I use import matplotlib.image as mpimg , it executes good
    But when I use from PIL import image I still get a error,
    Error:--    from PIL import image
    ImportError: cannot import name 'image'

This is really a pain. Can some one please tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use pillow 5.0? Since this seems to be a problem with this particular version, using an older version would probably solve this issue.

Comment: There is no such reason for me to use pillow 5.0.0
But I do not know how to install lower versions ?

Comment: Btw. you have a typo it is `from PIL import Image` with a capital `I` , not `image`. So if this persists, just install some previous version of pillow.

Comment: I had to install pillows using anaconda then in juypter I .  from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("./apples.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)

Answer (score 12):

**Matplotlib** requires **PIL(*Python Imaging Library*)** to work with `.jpg` format. To use it you need to install **[Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/)** (*which is the fork of PIL*).

**Installation Using PIP**

```
pip install pillow 
      or 
pip3 install pillow
```

**Installation Using Conda**

```
conda install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install PIL. Make sure you are using anaconda python distro. Go to [this link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pillow) or write this command to install PIL directly

```
 conda install -c anaconda pillow
```